# Documenting code with plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, openoffice-calc

I have tried to find a way to plot a graph where the x-axis wraps at a specified position and then continues at 0 to the right of the max value.
I am attaching an example where the x-axis wraps at 720, e.g. 720 == 0.
[image: graph with x-axis wrapped at 720]
It does not matter which tool to use as long it is easy to install on Linux (Ubuntu)

I am trying to assign a x-label column to my data serie where the x axis is in column B and data in column D and x-labels in column C.[image]
but that does not work for me, e.g. the x-axis in above example spans from 685 to 735 instead of 685 to 720 then to 15

So using line diagram instead of scatter as @pnuts did solved my problem.[image]

Comment: It's pretty unclear. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @pnuts answer below has the plot I want but I do not know how to get the proper labels on the axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of x values for the x-axis apply the remainder after x has been divided by `720`:

[image: SO43723948 example]

Comment: This looks exactly like I want it but I do not understand how you got the labels to be column B. I do not think I can add image in comment so I will try to update my question on how it looks like if I try to assign a different column for x-labels

Comment: I had no problem with content of the B column. Just that I do not understand how to get those values as labels.

Comment: Yes I did because that is what I always use. I will try the line chart

Comment: But the diagram does not looks as nice as a scatter when the x data points are irregular. Will see if I can post process my numbers to get them more as regular sampled points.